# Castle Windsor only instantiates one instance of the service, even though the lifestyle is set to Transient or PerWebRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am developing an application using MVC 3 and Castle Windsor, among others of course. I am having trouble getting Windsor to instantiate more than one object - even though the service might be registered with Transient or PerWebRequest.

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISession>().LifestylePerWebRequest().ImplementedBy<SessionImpl>());
```

This is all the relevant code as far as I'm aware. Resolving for ISession works fine, receiving a SessionImpl object.

SessionImpl is just a dummy object I created to show the problem:

```
public class SessionImpl : ISession
{
    public SessionImpl()
    {
         //Called once   
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Called once 
    }
}
```

I first noticed the problem when the ISession I got on the next request was already disposed - so I am sure I am getting the same ISession every time. Any ideas what I can have done wrong? It says Castle Windsor 3.0.0 in Solution Explorer -> References.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [lifestyle mismatch](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Debugger-views.ashx#Potential_Lifestyle_Mismatches_6). Fix it.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is indeed correct. Thanks :) two notes though: 1) There was no "Potential Lifestyle Mismatches" item - only 'All Components', 'All Services', and 'Objects Tracked By Release Policy' and 2) I almost figured you would answer me! You're the answerer on most Windsor questions I've googled.